# Why thread cannot update the ArrayList field?

Tags: java, multithreading

My structure looks like :

```
public class ReadCSV {

    volatile List<FlightDetails> detail;


 main()  {

    ReadCSV obj=new ReadCSV();

    obj.detail=Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<FlightDetails>());

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                ...
                //pass the object along
                readAndParseFile("someFile.csv",obj);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                ...
            }

               // prints  Alright
            System.out.println(obj.detail.get(0).getDep_loc());
        }       
    }).start();

    // Throws AIOB Exception
    System.out.println(obj.detail.get(0).getArr_loc());
}

static void readAndParseFile(String csvFileName, ReadCSV obj) { 

...
..
//make changes to the object
 obj.detail.add()

// works fine

}
```

While passing the object without the thread, the changes are made.But the changes are not reflected even after making the field `Volatile`.

1) what is wrong in the above code?
2) Is it alright to follow this approach?
3) what is the general way to do such jobs?

I am very new to multi threading .

Comment: You ask someone else to collect some items from the library into the basket at your door. [`start`] While that someone saunters away [`run`], you look into the basket [`println`]: nothing there, and you are annoyed. Reasonable? No. You have to wait for your helper's return...

Comment: In other words, maybe the new thread has not actually put anything in the list yet. Wait a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Thread object that does some task and you want to see the results, wait for its termination.

```
 Thread p = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     //...
 });  // no start here
 p.start();  // let it run
 p.join();   // wait for its end
```

There is not much gain in executing another thread while the starting thread has nothing better to do than to wait for the started thread's end.

Comment: I don't believe I missed that :) Can you please suggest the way I have followed by passing the object ? I felt bit uneasy by doing so.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a subclass of Thread, pass the List via the constructor. Not sure what this main method is in the snippets of your question.

Comment: Thank you :) It's the actual main method.

Comment: @rohansethi, There is almost never a good reason to extend the `Thread` class.  If you want to make a named class with a constructor (Laune's suggestion), then make your class implement `Runnable`, and then pass a new instance of your class as the argument to the constructor of a vanilla `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wait till your reader thread has finished.

you can use futures or Thread.join()

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)